# How to handle Keyboard Events from Subview in Parent View

Tags: ios, swift

I'm fairly new to iOS development and I ran into a problem which seems simple yet I cannot solve it whichever way I try.

I have a custom view class `@IBDesignable class ValidatedInputFieldView: UIView` that hold 2 UI elements.
One of those is `UITextField`.

`ValidatedInputFieldView` is added to its parent view `class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate`.

I want `ViewController` to respond to `textFieldShouldReturn` event from `UITextField`, and not the `ValidatedInputFieldView` where the `UITextField` is in.

I've tried exposing the `delegate` field of the `UITextView`:

```
@IBOutlet var textFieldDelegate:UITextFieldDelegate?
```

And setting it in the `ValidatedInputFieldView`:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    xibSetup()
    contentTextField.delegate = textFieldDelegate
}
```

And then linking it in the IB using the workaround:
*Declare the outlet's type as AnyObject or NSObject, connect objects to the outlet using Interface Builder, then change the outlet's type back to the protocol*.

But it simply does not work.

Debug says the object is `nil`.

I'm having trouble understanding how are those events that happen in Subview passed to the Parent view and what should I use to expose delegates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical style I like to follow is to keep the items contained in their Views. What I would do is put the `textFieldShouldReturn` function in the `ValidateInputView` and set the delegate of the `UITextField` to the `ValidateInputView`. Then, in the `textFieldShouldReturn` function, post a notification using

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("textFieldFunction", object: self)
```

and make sure you are listening in the `ViewController` for this with:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: Selector("textFieldFunction:"),
    name: "textFieldFunction",
    object: nil)
```

and create the function `textFieldFunction` in the `ViewController` to handle it like this:

```
func textFieldFunction(notification: NSNotification) {
    //Put code to handle return press here
}
```

Make sure you put this in the `ViewController` as well:

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

OR for no notification

Use the solution in this sample project:
https://mega.nz/#!koYDTZpa!uGZ6oUbKxRaWuGSM9FbCuV0t8oz5mtu35rZlLEL7Ehs

Sorry, I would post code, but there isn't much since it is mostly all through the IB.

Comment: Tnx for answer. From what I know `NSNotificationCenter` should be used when 1:N responses are needed. Isn't my case 1:1?

Comment: You're absolutely correct! Thanks for the insight on that. It makes sense and I will be sure to follow that guideline in all of my projects. I will attempt to solve your problem using delegates and edit the post if I come up with a clean solution.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I missed the part where it sets delegate to self.